# Can I control visibility of CiviCRM profiles that are used for "View/Edit Drupal User Account" using permissions and/or ACLs?

Tags: drupal, permissions, acl, user-account, roles

I want to set up some profiles that are visible and editable only to Drupal users with a given role. However it looks like regardless of the permission settings I use, all users can see the profiles in their user account. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Can you explain how you think you have fine grained control over permissions to see a Profile?

Comment: The approach I've taken is to turn off all the profile-related permissions and custom field access permissions in Drupal's permissioning, and then set up Civi ACL's to enable relevant groups of users to view and access given profiles and custom fields. It sort of works, but what I'm seeing is, that regardless of the user's role, when they edit their user account they can see the tabs with the names of the profiles. If they click on one of the tabs they get an error message. I guess I could hide the tabs with CSS, but I shouldn't need to do that. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If this is problematic it could be easier to provide these as Webforms which have fine grained access settings

Comment: Note that unless you use some other level of acl in drupal the webform 'node' itself will be visible to anon, just the 'form' part which can be hidden via the webform settings

Comment: Yep. I'm using Nodeaccess in this case I think to control which roles get to see which nodes.